# Criar um chat com todos os comentários

Tags: suporte

Já vi um moderador do SOpt mover todos os comentários de uma resposta para um chat.

Gostaria de saber se nós (usuários) podemos fazer isso, e como fazer.

Comment: Não, não é possível.

Comment: Po, que triste. Poderia ter um "privilégio" disso. Valeu!

Comment: O que pode acontecer é quando aparecer aquele link de criar o chat ele move os comentários para sala mas não remove eles da postagem.

Comment: @rray [meta-tag:status-intencional]?

Comment: E quanto ao sinalizar aos moderadores solicitando tal conversão?

Comment: Sinalizar como "precisa de atenção dos moderadores" e descrever solicitando isso? Por mim, 10!

Comment: :D... na verdade a intenção era comentar e acabei postando no campo de resposta.. rs.. Abs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível para usuários comuns. Apenas moderadores diamante possuem recursos para converter comentários em chat.